# What is the new approach to get user profile in Django 1.6?

Tags: python, django

I'm quite new to Django. I'm trying to get user profile with the help of `request.user.get_profile()` but there is a warning that the use of `AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE` has been deprecated.

I have a line in my settings.py: `AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE = "log_viewer.Configs"` where `Configs` is a model with fields to keep user profile settings.

What is the new approach of doing this?

Comment: You don't have to switch to a custom user (which could involve a complicated schema change) to use Django 1.6. To deal with the deprecation warnings, all you have to do is update replace `AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE` and `get_profile()` in your code. If you're using a one to one field, then it can be as easy as using `request.user.profile`, as Daniel's answer suggests.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

At first,I create a 'profile' for User:

```
User.profile = property(lambda u: Configs.objects.get_or_create(user=u)[0])
```

and use this to get the profile:

```
request.user.profile
```

more detail here: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/15937

Comment: There is no field 'profile' in class 'user'. Read 'AbstractUser' class in django.

Comment: I realized I have created profile property for User, and edited my answer.Thank you for pointing out and sorry for inconveniences