# Getting a user profile in Django 1.6

Tags: python, django

I've followed the instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21431477/what-is-the-new-approach-to-get-user-profile-in-django-1-6) to try and instantiate a user object so I can display a user's details in a 'My Profile' link on the front end. Like so:

```
User.profile = property(lambda u: UserProfile.objects.get(user=u)[0])
profile = request.user.profile
return render(request, 'profiles/index.html', {'profile': profile})
```

However, I'm getting

```
TypeError at /my-profile/

'UserProfile' object does not support indexing
```

I'm not entirely sure what I'm doing wrong as it seemed to work for the OP in the other thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `[0]` is strange, as `.get()` always returns a single `UserProfile`, provided it exists. If it doesn't, a `UserProfile.DoesNotExist` exception is raised.

The code you linked to uses `.get_or_create()`, which returns a *tuple*, the first element of which is the instance, the second is a boolean that says whether the instance was newly created or not. You want the first of these, that is element 0.

So basically you should change it back to what the linked answer uses, get_or_create:

```
User.profile = property(lambda u: UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(user=u)[0])
```

Comment: Yeah I thought I'd overlooked something obvious. So much for not pasting code! Thanks.

Comment: Can I pass profile to the template? When I print out {{ profile.email }} for example I get nothing returned. {{ profile }} returns 'UserProfile object'. I think it's linked to the profile table and not the auth_user table.

Comment: The user instance is the user, user.profile is the profile. You only pass the profile, it seems.

Comment: I'm confused, I need to pass User.profile through to the view? I've tried but again I get an object which I don't seem to have access to.

Comment: You should probably pass `{'user': request.user}`, then you can use `{{ user.email }}` and `{{ user.profile.your_custom_field }}` in the template.

Comment: Ah, I've got it now. Hopefully this will clear things up for other people as well. Thanks.

Comment: But I'm confused too -- the other answer that you linked to was trying to get old code to work with Django 1.6. Django 1.6 has a new way of dealing with users, this solution you're using is a hack to keep using the old way. You're writing new code?

Comment: Yes, this is a fresh application I'm writing. Any links/help to write it for the current version would be good.

Comment: I'm not really an expert as all our projects are still on 1.3, 1.4 or 1.5, but it's possible to make your own User object based on some base class these days, so you don't need separate users and profiles and that. But I don't know if it's the right away in all cases. See the docs from https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model